# OpenGL texture color issue

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, textures

I'm loading raw texture (with alpha channel) and displaying it in openGL everything is fine and texture displayed, but color is little bit darker than original. I already tried to turn of lighting, blending and dithering, but this doesn't helps.

I'm using mac osx.

Sample image

[image: Sample image]
http://postimage.org/image/2wi1x5jic/

Here's openGL texture loading source code:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA , width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &bytes[0]);
```

EDIT:

Thats very weird, I used example from http://forums.tigsource.com/index.php?topic=9560.0
and received same glitch ... So the problem not im my code, maybe driver options? Hm ...

SOLUTION:

Thanks @datenwolf, images were saved with sRrgb color profile. Problem is solved once I removed it and converted to RGB.

Comment: How are you viewing the original image?

Comment: I'm using Gimp, raw image format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you have GL_MODULATE set as texturing environment and the vertex colours are not white. Try setting the texture environment to GL_REPLACE.

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, your_texture);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE);
```

**EDIT**

Another problem may be a color profile embedded into the image. A image viewer may use this colour profile to implement color management, adjusting the colours for your monitor's colour profile. OpenGL as-it-is doesn't do color management; there is a extension, that framebuffers and textures are sRGB, this is kind of the smallest common denominator of colour management. But then you'd still have to transfer your input images to sRGB colour space.

I've a lengthy article in preparation the explains in depth how to do colour management with OpenGL. But it's far from complete.

Comment: I'm using raw image, exported from Gimp. It's in rgba format, I don't think it has any embedded information.

Comment: @lameDay: It's not necessarily a question of the embedded color profile. If GIMP simply writes colors in the sRGB colorspace rather than linearizing them, then you will need to load those textures in as sRGB textures.

Comment: Can you give code example? How can I do it in openGL? I tried to put GL_SRGB instead of GL_RGBA but it displayed white screen ...

Comment: @lameDay: Instead of _which_ GL_RGBA? The [internal format](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Format) (the third parameter) or the [pixel format](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Pixel_Transfer#Pixel_format) (the seventh parameter)? I'm guessing you changed the pixel format. Also, use sized internal formats, not unsized ones like GL_RGBA.

Comment: Thanks @datenwolf, images were saved with sRrgb color profile. Problem is solved once I removed it and converted to RGB.